# How to resolve NoSuchMethodError and appiumDriver error

Tags: android, selenium, appium, nosuchmethoderror

```
 package demo;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

  public class Test {

 RemoteWebDriver driver;
 public static void main(String[] args)throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{ 
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung S4");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.1");
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new 
    URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement keyword = driver.findElementByName("q");
    keyword.sendKeys("appium");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnK")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

}
}

Error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/ErrorCodes;Z)V
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:46)
>       at demo.Test.main(Test.java:31)

I have added all the essential Jars files. When i run the code nothing happens on appium server. Any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you recheck the code once "capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");"

and also jar related to "import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;"..

try import latest jar and run again.

```
  capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.browser");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethodError - Usually this exception was thrown, when you trying to access the methods which are not available at run time using reflection.

This error could be due to library(jars) version mismatch where some methods have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my java-client jar to the version 5.0.4 solved my problem. You can download it from the given link:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client

Also, make sure that your APK must exists in the src folder path.

C:\Users\abc\workspace\AppiumFirst\src

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You have to post it in the comment section below the question.